# building a custom freebsd kernel

Tags: freebsd, make, bsd

I am trying to build an arm64 version of the freebsd kernel that has realtek wireless drivers enabled.
I absolutely have to customize the kernel options as some of the drivers do not allow boot time enabling.

```
Makefile:122: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

This is the error that i get. I am on wsl 2 using ubuntu to attempt to make/build the files.
first i cloned the repo.

```
https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src.git
```

Next i cd'ed into the directory called freebsd-src... then i attempted to make just the base version doing this:

```
make buildkernel=GENERIC
```

Then i get the error mentioned at the top. I have read other posts that mention it being an indention issue\expecting tabs but getting spaces, but the directory does not (to my seeing) have the correct files to change the ruleset. It also does not have any configure / autoconf files. What could fix my issue?

Comment: FreeBSD is designed to be built on FreeBSD and not Ubuntu. For a start, `make` is different, which explains the error.

Comment: yeah that was it